# I want to use XPath 3.0 language support in javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, jquery-plugins

I need work with XPath in JavaScript or jQuery for XPath find 
but XPath language support should be 3.0 dom

Please help me about

Answer (score 1):

Saxon-JS provides support for XPath 3.1 as well as XSLT 3.0 running in the browser (Node.js support coming real soon...)

Details of the API are here:

http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!api/xpathEvaluate

It works with the browser-supplied XML DOM, just supply any Node as the contextItem parameter.

To use XSLT 3.0 with Saxon-JS you need a Saxon-EE license so you can pre-compile the stylesheets for execution in the browser. But if you only need XPath support, the library is free for use (but not open source).

Comment: is it working with HTML document in JavaScript on browser ?